# Google Chrome save web passwords option is disabled

Tags: google-chrome

I am using Google Chrome "Version 34.0.1847.131 m".

I used to be able to save web passwords, but the option is now disabled.

How can I re-enable?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try this:

> SyncDisabled = 0
>
> PasswordManagerEnabled = 1

```
Key Path: HKLM\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\
Value Type: REG_DWORD
```

Comment: Yoink!  Works like a charm...  I only needed `PasswordManagerEnabled`.  What does the other key do, `SyncDisabled`?

Comment: @kevinarpe stop Google Chrome from asking to set up Chrome with you Google Account when Chome is opened

Comment: how do you set these values?

Comment: Add these values in registry

Comment: For mac, where should these values be set?

Comment: It would be good to know, what are the types, I have no Chrome under Google, so I'm trying to create, but I have to guess the type (DWORD?).

Comment: @Ramraj this answer might be what you are looking for(You'll need to check the boxes, though): https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/122344/73675

Comment: @pulsarjune where I can find this file on mac?